# why code javascript ,not repeat the loop main wordpress

Tags: javascript

i cant write english
so, one question ,i hope understand you

why code javascript ,no repeat, in post ,every post.
i will affect every post image butt not work all post ,only first post working.not other post
of course,
attachment file image and code index.php my site[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hello world </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/responsive.css">

</head>
<body>
<header>
<!--prog menu home-->
<nav>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
  <?php
 wp_nav_menu( array(
'menu' => 'menu 1',
'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ,
 'container' => '' ,
 'theme_location' => 'navb-header'
) );
?>
  </div>
</div>
<li class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" onclick="openNav()"></li>
<a href="/" class="active">WallTure.Com<i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></a>
</nav>
<!--end prog menu home-->
<!--prog menu category-->
<section>
<div class="chip">
<a onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" ><i id="search" ></i>
  Search</a>
</div>
<div class="chip">
<a onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" ><i id="box"></i>
  Category</a>
</div>
</section>
<!--start body search-->
<div id="id01" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content-search animate">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
     Search The In Site
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end body search-->
<!--start body category-->
<div id="id02" class="modal">
  <form class="modal-content animate">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      Choose Category Wallpaper
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <?php wp_list_categories(array(
        'title_li'=>'',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'include' => array( 5,6,8,9,10,7,12,11 ) ));
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn button">Cancel</button>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!--end body category-->
<!--end prog menu category-->
</header>

<section><!--start post body-->
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'large'); ?>
<div class="bodypost">

<div class="post-img" >
<div class="ourdownload">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closedownload" onclick="closedownload()">&times;</a>
<div class="download-content">
  <li><?php the_time('d-m-y') ?> | <?php the_time('m-h') ?></li>
 <li> org size : 20*20</li>
 <li> other size : 20*20</li>

  </div>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-download fa-2x post-img-download" onClick="opendownload()" ></i>
<div class="ourinformation">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeinformation" onclick="closeinformation()">&times;</a>
<div class="information-content">

  <li>our size : 20*20</li>
 <li> org size : 20*20</li>
 <li> other size : 20*20</li>

  </div>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x post-img-note" onClick="openinformation()"></i>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
</div>
<div class="name-post"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a></div>
<div class="name-category"><?php the_category(', ') ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo '
<script>
function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
function opendownload(){
    var x=document.getElementsByClassName("ourdownload");
    x[0].style.width="100%";
    }
function closedownload(){var x=document.getElementsByClassName("ourdownload");
    x[0].style.width="0%";}
function openinformation(){var z=document.getElementsByClassName("ourinformation"); z[0].style.width = "100%";}
function closeinformation(){var z=document.getElementsByClassName("ourinformation"); z[0].style.width = "0%";}
</script> ' ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</section><!--end post body-->

<div class="number-body">
<div class="numall">
Total Wall : <?php //Count Published Posts Mandegarweb.com
echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'"); ?></div>
<div class="pagination">
<?php if (function_exists('mw_pagination')) mw_pagination(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<footer>Wallture.com & Wallture.ir beging 2015,2016,2017 continue ...</footer>
سس
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('id01');
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }if (event.target == modal2){
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the CODE you've tried.

Comment: fayaz i cant put code here ,I do not know

Comment: Use http://pastebin.com

Comment: there are so many things wrong in your CODE that I can't even begin to solve them all. I'll give you some hint: (1) Learn how to add Javascript in WordPress properly. (2) Use jQuery and CSS class to manipulate style, don't use ID or inline Javascript event (3) Add `wp_head()` function call just before the ending `</head>` tag.

Comment: ok bro fayaz ,i know alot problem ,but later slove problem,now problem me repeat javascript for post ,of course again thank you,i am Beginner :)

Comment: I understand, another reason I'm not answering is because this post is likely to be deleted by moderators before I'm able to check and answer. This is Javascript question, not specific to WordPress. So better if you post the question in Stackoverflow. There you'll get help quickly.

Comment: oky bro fayaz,of course again again thanks you one world

Comment: @Fayaz Please, do not encourage people to link to code outside this page. Instead, let them paste the code in here. If the link is gone, the question can  not be understood by any later reader.

Comment: @kaiser actually my intention was to post it back here, as he said he can't do it here. Could've explained how to do it here, but wasn't sure if he would understand because of the language barrier.

Comment: When the language is a barrier, then he will have to get some friend to assist. If a common language is not in use, questions are useless for later readers—English is not my and most other users mother tongue either. About the length: There is a reason that low rep users can not post such amounts of code. They are forced to narrow it down to the real problem. This helps overall question quality.

Comment: oky i thanks for you @kaiser and fayaz ,tried learn english, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you used `#id` to set javascript action (event). Use `.class` in jQuery selector. Open console in your browser and see javascript errors.

Comment: thanks for you ,but i no use id please see pastebin.com/DiCQiYG2

Comment: hi mehdi bro , see code html, Especially loop main wordpress ????? why no repeat java ???